# Slider Revolution showing half the page instead of full width

Tags: wordpress, slider-revolution

I am updating one of our sites, and the issue I came into is the slider in the Hero is appearing to be half of the page until I refresh the page without reloading it (switching tabs, opening inspect, etc). I haven't seen this before, does anyone know a solution to this other than resetting to the previous version?

I have tried

- refreshing the page (Obviously did nothing, but just in case it was a one-off)
- Inspecting to see why it's happening (Even after opening the inspect, then reloading, I was still unable to replicate it inside the inspect, it just loads correctly, then reloading in full width, non-inspect gets me the issue again)
- looking on the plugin page (nothing there)

For now, I have just reverted to the old version until this is solved.